# Feodra 32: Internet not working inside Docker Containers

Tags: networking, docker, fedora, docker-compose

I have a fresh installed Fedora 32, on which I have installed docker (from these [instructions](https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/)).

```sh
[muhammadtaqi@muhammadtaqi-hp-probook-450-g5 ~]$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           19.03.11
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.14.3
 Git commit:        42e35e6
 Built:             Sun Jun  7 21:16:58 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.11
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.14.3
  Git commit:       42e35e6
  Built:            Sun Jun  7 00:00:00 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.3
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10+dev
  GitCommit:        fbdbaf85ecbc0e077f336c03062710435607dbf1
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:
```

Afterwards i pull the imgaes and start container, but it exists as it starts..

```
[muhammadtaqi@muhammadtaqi-hp-probook-450-g5 ~]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
94d0275dcdb5        hello-world         "/hello"            8 minutes ago       Exited (0) 8 minutes ago                       vibrant_ptolemy
d5a79a7073f0        hello-world         "/hello"            11 minutes ago      Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                       gracious_jones
[muhammadtaqi@muhammadtaqi-hp-probook-450-g5 ~]$ docker start gracious_jones
gracious_jones
[muhammadtaqi@muhammadtaqi-hp-probook-450-g5 ~]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
94d0275dcdb5        hello-world         "/hello"            9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                       vibrant_ptolemy
d5a79a7073f0        hello-world         "/hello"            11 minutes ago      Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                       gracious_jones
```

The container is up for some seconds, in another terminal, I logged-In to that container and `ping google.com`, and ping was not working.

Any solution to it, I've been doing the same on Ubuntu it works there, but on Fedora 32 I'm facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The docker is unable to use nftables, which are by default used in fedora32 to manage firewall rules. You will need to update **/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf** file and set the value of FirewallBackend as:

```
FirewallBackend=iptables
```

Comment: there were 3 files inside `/etc/firewalld/`

`firewalld.conf -> firewalld-workstation.conf`
`firewalld-server.conf`
`firewalld-standard.conf`
`firewalld-workstation.conf`

I have update in all 3 step by step, still same issue.

Comment: you might need to restart firewall/docker or host

Comment: ah, and this one **firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0**

Comment: ```
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: docker0
success
```

Comment: no success even after running the command and reboot the system as well.

Comment: is ping the only the issue? can you connect use curl or ping other containers?